# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable in Appium. Can find but cannot send.keys

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, python-appium

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable in Appium. Can find and click but cannot send.keys

The app is Hybrid Ionic app. I could only find the field with UIAutomator, but it's too long and won't work for iOS. Xpath doesn't work as well.

Is there any suggestion? As you can see sleep and click before sending doesn't help.

Writing in Appium Python.

```
from config import desired_caps
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
import time


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_success_login(self):

        email = self.driver.find_element_by_id('emailInput')
        email.click()
        time.sleep(6)
        email.send_keys("a@gmail.com")
        time.sleep(6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: Were you able to send key to the element from appium desktop inspector?

Comment: Yes I can, it also works when I use below mentioned, however I want id so my code works for Android and iOS and be more readable. 

email = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").index(0).clickable(true).instance(0)')

Comment: Can you provide the html of that input field? it looks like you are getting an element that cannot be used for editing the input field. There are tag in ionic that won't allow it.

Comment: Sorry for late response, which tag? unfortunately I cannot provide html